# How to numerically find initial values of a differential equation that gives us a solution that goes to 0 at infinity.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, initial-value-problems

I am new to numerically solving differential equations and the problem I'm working with involves finding the initial values for a second order differential equation that would give us a solution that goes to 0 as x goes to infinity. I will provide an example, for which I already know an answer to.
$$y'' - y = 0$$
With initial conditions of $y(0) = -1$ and $y'(0) = -1$ we get a solution that goes to 0 as $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} y(x) =0$.

I will provide the code that I use to plot the result in jupyter notebook:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def model(y,x):
       u,v=y
       dydx=[v,u]
       return dydx
x=np.linspace(0,5,100)
sol=odeint(model,[1,-1],x)
plt.plot(x,sol[:,0])
```

Here we get the following plot: [y'(0) = -1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4u5w.png)

Now if we were to change the initial value at $y'(0) = 0.99$ we would get the function that would go to infinity.
Here is the plot with the said change: [y'(0) = -0.99](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSCua.png)
My goal is to find a way to find the value of $y'(0)$ that gives us a solution to a differential equation, which goes to $0$ at infinity.
If there exists a method for this already, I would appreciate knowing it's name so that I can learn it. I also want to know if the method I use for numerically solving the differential equation matters for such a problem. (I used a method from scipy called odeint, I'm curious if I should be using something else).

I am also new to stack exchange so if the way I formatted the question is not ideal, please go easy on me.

Comment: That is hard to impossible. Due to numerical errors you will always move away from the stable solution and grow exponentially away from it. What works is to find an approximation of the stable solution/manifold close to the saddle point and use that to continue a finite BVP solution, using a suitable boundary condition.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you for your reply. I am realising that numerical error will indeed give lead me to encountering that problem. Could you please tell me how I can apply boundary condition to the problem and approximate a stable solution?

Comment: One approach or set of approaches is known as [far field approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bode%5D+%22far+field%22). There might also be something FEM related (?) called "infinite segments" or "segments at infinity" or the like.

Comment: I will look into what you suggested, thank you

Comment: In the example, you would find $y'=u(y)=-y$ as equation for the stable manifold, and you would solve a BVP with $y'(b)=u(y(b))=-y(b)$ as second boundary condition to $y(0)=-1$ on $[0,b]$.

Comment: There are techniques for numerically determining stable and other invariant manifolds but that is active research and is likely overkill for such a problem.

Comment: @whpowell96 I was asked by my professor if I could do it, so I assumed this is something not too out of scope of what a bachelor's student should be able to do. He mentioned shooting method and I learned it, but I can't see how it can be useful here since I'd have to "shoot" to infinity